# React Router Form and Action does not log the formsubmission

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-router, react-router-dom

I attempted to use the `react-router` `action` and `Form` components, but it appears that the `action` function is not being invoked, and no errors are showing in the console. I have already implemented the `Data` router, exported the `action` function, and included it in the Router. Any insights on why the `action` function might not be triggering?

I've been following the React Router documentation, and my main concern is the absence of errors or warnings for debugging purposes.

Login component:

```
import React from 'react';
import { Form } from 'react-router-dom';

export async function action({ request }) {
  console.log(request);
  const data = await request.formData();

  const formSubmission = {
    email: data.get('email'),
    password: data.get('password'),
  };

  console.log(formSubmission);
}

const AdminLogin = () => {
  return (
    <div>
      <Form>
        <input
          type="text"
          placeholder="Enter email or User ID"
          name="email"
          autoComplete="username"
        />

        <input
          type="password"
          placeholder="Enter Password"
          name="password"
          autoComplete="current-password"
        />
        <button>Log In</button>
      </Form>
    </div>
  );
};

export default AdminLogin;
```

Router component:

```
import {
  Route,
  createBrowserRouter,
  createRoutesFromElements,
  RouterProvider,
  redirect
} from "react-router-dom";
import { Home, MainNav } from './Assets/User components/UserImports';
import './Assets/User components/StyledComponents/style.css';
import LogIn, { action as userAction } from "./Assets/User components/LogIn";
import Dashboard from "./Assets/Admin components/Dashboard";
import AdminLayout from "./Assets/Admin components/AdminLayout";
import EditDeals from "./Assets/Admin components/EditDeals";
import { loader } from "./Assets/User components/Deals";
import AdminLogin, { action } from "./Assets/Admin components/AdminLogin";

function App() {
  const takeRouter = createBrowserRouter(createRoutesFromElements(
    <>
      <Route path="*" element={<code>404 Not Found</code>} />
      <Route path="/" element={<MainNav />}>
        <Route path="adminlogin" action={action} element={<AdminLogin />} />
        <Route index element={<Home />} loader={loader} errorElement={<h1>Oh! there was an error!</h1>} />
        <Route path="login" action={userAction} element={<LogIn />} />
      </Route>
      <Route path="admin" element={<AdminLayout />} loader={async () => {
        const loggedIn = false;
        return loggedIn === false ? redirect('/adminlogin') : null;
      }}>
        <Route index element={<Dashboard />} />
        <Route path="editdeals" element={<EditDeals />} />
      </Route>
    </>
  ));

  return (
    <>
      <div className="app">
        <RouterProvider router={takeRouter} />
      </div>
    </>
  );
}

export default App;
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By default, the `Form` component uses GET submissions, which don't trigger route actions.

See [GET submissions](https://reactrouter.com/en/main/components/form#get-submissions):

> The default method is "get". Get submissions will not call an action.
> Get submissions are the same as a normal navigation (user clicks a
> link) except the user gets to supply the search params that go to the
> URL from the form.

Specify a [`method`](https://reactrouter.com/en/main/components/form#method) to the form, anything *other than* `"get"` should trigger the route action.

> This determines the HTTP verb to be used. The same as plain HTML form
> method, except it also supports "put", "patch", and "delete" in
> addition to "get" and "post". The default is "get".

Also, you should be explicit with the `button` element's `type` attribute *even though* `type="submit"` is the default when unspecified.

Example:

```
const AdminLogin = () => {
  return (
    <div>
      <Form method="post"> // <-- specify non-"get" method
        <input
          type="text"
          placeholder="Enter email or User ID"
          name="email"
          autoComplete="username"
        />

        <input
          type="password"
          placeholder="Enter Password"
          name="password"
          autoComplete="current-password"
        />
        <button type="submit"> // <-- explicit button type
          Log In
        </button>
      </Form>
    </div>
  );
};
```

Answer (score -1):

You have two scenarios:

1.You're missing the `onSubmit` handler for the Form component.

2.You need to prevent the `default` form submission behavior to avoid a page reload.

This is updated version from your `Login` component.

Try this and let me know.

```js
import React from 'react';
import { Form } from 'react-router-dom';

export async function action({ request }) {
  console.log(request);
  const data = await request.formData();

  const formSubmission = {
    email: data.get('email'),
    password: data.get('password'),
  };

  console.log(formSubmission);
}

const AdminLogin = () => {
  const handleSubmit = async (e) => {
    e.preventDefault();

    // Invoke the action function here
    await action({
      request: new Request(e.target, {
        method: 'POST',
        body: new FormData(e.target),
      }),
    });
  };

  return (
    <div>
      <Form onSubmit={handleSubmit}>
        <input
          type="text"
          placeholder="Enter email or User ID"
          name="email"
          autoComplete="username"
        />

        <input
          type="password"
          placeholder="Enter Password"
          name="password"
          autoComplete="current-password"
        />
        <button type="submit">Log In</button>
      </Form>
    </div>
  );
};

export default AdminLogin;
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/16.6.3/umd/react.production.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-dom/16.6.3/umd/react-dom.production.min.js"></script>
```